# Add image from one canvas context to another canvas context

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I need method which works like `addImage`, but only for a canvas context.

How can I add an image from one canvas context to another canvas context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ctx.drawImage` with another canvas as the argument (or a `<video>` even)

The syntax is just `ctx.drawImage(someCanvas, 0, 0)`

You can even draw one canvas onto itself, which can be useful for drawing overviews or minimaps.